# How can the ask question page be improved in the case the validation checks out OK?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, ask-question-form

When trying to post a question, a validation step checks if the question is ready to publish. I assume that this workflow was constructed very deliberately and with a lot of feedback. Yet, I find it somewhat confusing:

1. When everything is OK, I don't see the point in making me click submit again. I have never seen a form where I need to re-submit if all validation checks out. What is the benefit of this? I'm sure this was done deliberately but, as an end-user, it's really strange.
2. In the beginning, I overlooked the OK message, which sits at the top right. I was scrolling up and down furiously, trying to find the validation error. Clearly, something wasn't OK... Why else would I be presented the form again? After a few times of this, I now have learned that I simply need to scroll down and press the button again.

Is this really the best way the ask question form can be constructed in cases where everything is OK?

---

The validation message in question:

[image]

Comment: Yeah I can only agree here. This is not good UX or UI.

Comment: "validation" "ready to publish" Ha ha ha.

Comment: Yeah-2. This is kind of counter-intuitive to what we learn about form validation - it is not as if the extra couple of seconds the user spends on the question the system already told is perfectly fine are of any significance. A form either submits or fails to submit due to a validation error - making the user click again breaks that idiom, yet here we are...

Comment: The button you pushed was _review your question_, right? Which gave you that feedback and offered a button to _publish your question_, right? I believe the review step is for more than just system validation; it also offers an opportunity to eyeball rendering before committing. Admittedly, having the wizard context (step 1/2, step 2/2, etc.) in a sidebar card is a little wonky... but the submit button text is pretty clear.

Comment: @canon: The question is already rendered just below.

Comment: @canon I cannot tell you what the button said because I didn't read it... It looked like the obvious submit button. This seems like typical user behavior to me.

Comment: "Do you really want to publish your new question and add it to an already quite high pile of existing questions and that may not be very useful, even though our not very advanced automatic systems cannot find something obviously wrong with it now? Then please go ahead." A bit exaggerated but one could see it as a "Do you really want this?" type of message.

Comment: _"I cannot tell you what the button said because I didn't read it."_ Submit buttons may mean different things based on the context. Seems unreasonable that they'd  label a button, _review your question_, and someone would be surprised a _review_ step... for lack of reading.

Comment: @canon I disagree. Breaking standard form convention by replacing a "submit" button with something different is still bad UX, even if the user ignores explanatory text on the button. Either the "review" button needs to be more distinct from submit, or they need to ditch the concept. This is in addition to the fact that scrolling the user back up the page without warning, especially if there is actually _nothing_ to review, is jarring and confusing for all parties.

Comment: @zcoop98 Submit is still "submit" in the technical "form" sense. What that button accomplishes beyond "submitting the form" or how it's used in the context of a wizard or whatever, e.g. submit for review, depends. I agree that the question wizard fails in a number of ways to establish appropriate context and provide feedback. That said, the _review_ button isn't even a submit button; the _publish_ button is. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Something that would seem to be so simple to create yet fails miserably, I too really really despise this user interface.

Comment: @JonH One would think that competitors would get it right easily given this, but Codidact for example puts the title below the question body on the ask page. It seems difficult to get it completely right. On the other hand, the issue here cannot be a complete deal breaker or there wouldn't be millions of questions asked new every year. We are probably well trained to simply find the right button and click on it as quickly as possible.

Comment: I don't know what it looks like when it does detect a problem, but the handful of questions I've submitted while this feature has been active, I thought I misclicked or scanned the page for an error and just clicked the button again. Shrugged it off as a one-off error of the site, not a problem with my submission. It is confusing UX indeed.

Answer (score 4):

I like the idea to have a review step before posting the question! Even if it contains no errors. It is a 'think again' step, and I appreciate it. Though I prefer the way the classic edit mode in some Wikipedia's does it - there are two buttons, *post* (blue) and *preview*. Below, a screenshot of the German Wikipedia:

[image]

Stack Overflow could also have that. The preview shows the question, as it would *actually* look, after submitting (without the text entry, and only 'edit' and 'submit' buttons at the bottom).

Fully agree with point 2, the error message should not be top right, in a location where the user does not expect it. It should be below the text entry, where the action happens. The site may scroll to the message.

BTW, there is another UX problem: The submit button changes from 'review your question' to 'post your question', even if there *are* errors in the question. That should not happen. It should be 'review your question' until all errors are gone.

Comment: That is not only for the German Wikipedia. That is (at least) for the [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) and [Danish Wikipedia](https://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forside) as well.

Comment: Good point, @PeterMortensen, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not to indicate "Yes your question is OK, now click on *Submit*", but:

"*Your question makes sense, and seems legitimate. Now, **check for a duplicate** before posting*"

This is confirmed by possible duplicates being shown next to the aforementioned UI.

This can also encourage people to:

- Perform visual verification: Is my code well shown?
- Proofread: Quickly read and maybe find mistake(s)
- See if the question is too long by viewing it from the top

For me, **the feature is useful but can be improved**:

- In [Help people and automation of some detection to prevent high backlog review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413441), I proposed multiple ways to improve it, specifically by using machine learning or other checks for insults/ spam/ missing code.
- Upgrade the duplicate detection, and make the duplicate area more visible. Actually, for me, it's hard to compare posts with others, and also the system doesn't really seem to find relevant posts.
- Add suggestions for improvement, such as "*You have only one tag, maybe you could add more?*".